# How do I determine the ARC path for a particular drive letter in Windows?

Tags: windows

I'm trying to edit my BOOT.INI file but I'm unsure what ARC path I need to use to reference a particular drive letter. There is a kb article that almost seems like it tells you how to do this but instead is useless at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/155222

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am researching this for you. In the mean time, I found the following reference.

```
multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)        = "Primary Channel, C:"
multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(0)        = "Primary Channel, System Partition"
multi(0)disk(0)cdrom(%u)                   = "CD-ROM, Variable"
ramdisk(0)                                 = "RamDisk"
net(0)                                     = "Network"
multi(0)disk(0)fdisk(0)                    = "Diskette A:"
multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(1)partition(0)        = "Secondary Channel, Partition 0"
multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(1)partition(%d)       = "Secondary Channel, Variable Partition"
multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(1)partition(1)        = "Secondary Channel, Partition 0"
multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(%d)       = "Primary Channel, Variable Partition"
multi(0)disk(0)fdisk(1)partition(0)        = "Diskette B:, Partition 0"
multi(0)disk(0)fdisk(0)partition(0)        = "Diskette A:, Partition 0"
multi(0)video(0)monitor(0)                 = "ConsoleOut, Monitor"
multi(0)key(0)keyboard(0)                  = "ConsoleIn, Keyboard"
multi(0)disk(0)fdisk(1)                    = "Diskette B:"
eisa(0)disk(0)fdisk(0)                     = "EISA Diskette A:"
eisa(0)disk(0)fdisk(1)partition(0)         = "EISA Diskette B:, Partition 0"
eisa(0)disk(0)fdisk(0)partition(0)         = "EISA Diskette A:, Partition 0"
```

Will list the related links I find below:

- [Admin XP](http://www.adminxp.com/windows2000/index.php?aid=46)
- [Windows XP ARC naming conventions](http://www.trcb.com/Computers-and-Technology/Windows-XP/Windows-XP-ARC-Naming-Conventions-1432.htm)
- [ARC boot path question SATA vs IDE boot order](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.windowsxp.general/browse_thread/thread/3fc59b4775c12364/cf95577844397b1f?hl=en&ie=UTF-8&oe=utf-8&q=ARC+boot.ini#cf95577844397b1f) -- interesting reading on a Microsoft group.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to read long manuals, postings and guides anymore.
Download [ArcPaths utility](http://www.boyans.net/ArcPaths/ArcPaths.htm) and run, it will show you exactly the ARC paths for your partitions/drives.

Comment: You publish many useful tools for interactive use – have you considered documenting how they work (or open-sourcing them)?

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://www.dewassoc.com/kbase/multiboot/boot_ini.htm) explains all about ARC paths, the info is old, but appears to still be relevent. This may guide you in the right direction.

Comment: Hm doesn't really tell me a whole lot about investigating my own system, and for some reason puts rdisk in front of disk (mine has it the other way around).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do this on a machine without the .NET framework, you can get the information from [Sysinternals winobj](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896657.aspx); find the "global" drive letter and look up the device - eventually this will lead you to the arcname!

Answer (score 0):

Have built out numerous dual boot systems since Windows 2000.  Did it without ArcPaths and each time it was a pain.  No more.  No more having to jump around in BIOS, no more trial and error.  Used ArcPaths once this morning and will use it for another dual boot system being built later today.  It cut down the build time by at least half an hour.